Reference for $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{a x^4+b x^3+cx^2}dx\;$?
In my research I encounter an integral of the form
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\rm e}^{\large ax^{4}\ +\ bx^{3}\ +\ cx^{2}}\,{\rm d}x\qquad a < 0,\quad b, c \in \mathbb{R}
$$
So the integral is convergent.

If I suppress the cubic term by a linear transformation it looks to me like the Pearcy integral:
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\rm e}^{\large xu^{4}\ +\ yu^{2}\ + zu}\,{\rm d}u\qquad x < 0,\quad y,z
 \in \mathbb{R}
$$
except the leading coefficient $x$ is now real instead of being $purely$ imaginary.
If I change my variables I will be integrating from
$-{\rm i}\infty\ \mbox{to}\ {\rm i}\infty$ hence it is not the same.

Does anyone know any reference for this type of integrals as a special function ?.
Thanks a lot

Here, first link after just googling the integral name: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1601.03615 Start at (1) there and the rest is being shown. First: Notice, that you can pull out one constant in your integral by just a suitable substitution. Second: You need to analytically continue your integral/function.

Thanks a lot! this is exactly what I needed. I guess it is more appreciated if I can write my solutions in terms of well known classical functions.

$$\int_{-\infty }^{\infty } \exp \left(-a x^4+b x^3+c x^2\right) \, dx=\\\sum _{m=0}^{\infty } \sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \int_{-\infty }^{\infty } \frac{e^{-a x^4} \left(b x^3\right)^n \left(c x^2\right)^m}{n! m!} \, dx=\\\sum _{m=0}^{\infty
   } \sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \frac{a^{\frac{1}{4} (-1-2 m-3 n)} \left((-b)^n+b^n\right) c^m \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{4} (1+2 m+3 n)\right)}{4 m! n!}=\\\frac{\Gamma \left(\frac{1}{4}\right) \sum _{m=0}^{\infty } \sum _{n=0}^{\infty }
   \frac{\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)_{\frac{m}{2}+\frac{3 n}{4}} \left(-\frac{b}{a^{3/4}}\right)^n \left(\frac{c}{\sqrt{a}}\right)^m}{m! n!}}{4 \sqrt[4]{a}}+\frac{\Gamma \left(\frac{1}{4}\right) \sum _{m=0}^{\infty } \sum
   _{n=0}^{\infty } \frac{\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)_{\frac{m}{2}+\frac{3 n}{4}} \left(\frac{b}{a^{3/4}}\right)^n \left(\frac{c}{\sqrt{a}}\right)^m}{m! n!}}{4 \sqrt[4]{a}}$$
for: $a>0, b,c \in \mathbb R$
Double infinte series can be expressed by Srivastava-Daoust function.

Let us define your integral as
$$I(a,b,c)\equiv\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{ax^4+bx^3+cx^2}\,\mathrm dx$$
Notice
$$4a\dfrac{\partial I}{\partial a}=\int_{-\infty}^\infty 4ax^4e^{ax^4+bx^3+cx^2}\,\mathrm dx$$
$$3b\dfrac{\partial I}{\partial b}=\int_{-\infty}^\infty 3bx^3e^{ax^4+bx^3+cx^2}\,\mathrm dx$$
$$2c\dfrac{\partial I}{\partial c}=\int_{-\infty}^\infty 2cx^2e^{ax^4+bx^3+cx^2}\,\mathrm dx$$
If we were to add these terms up we'd have
$$4a\dfrac{\partial I}{\partial a}+3b\dfrac{\partial I}{\partial b}+2c\dfrac{\partial I}{\partial c}=\int_{-\infty}^\infty x(4ax^3+3bx^2+2cx)e^{ax^4+bx^3+cx^2}\,\mathrm dx$$
where
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty x(4ax^3+3bx^2+2cx)e^{ax^4+bx^3+cx^2}\,\mathrm dx\overset{\text{IBP}}{=}-I$$
And so your integral may be found by solving the following PDE (with adequate boundary conditions):
$$4a\dfrac{\partial I}{\partial a}+3b\dfrac{\partial I}{\partial b}+2c\dfrac{\partial I}{\partial c}+I=0$$

Maybe something of the sort $I(0,0,-1)=\Gamma(\frac{1}{2})$ or $I(-1,0,0)=2\Gamma(\frac{5}{4})$
